# SQL in Java. Select Password ( md5 ) issue. rs not executing query, throwing exception

Tags: java, mysql, sql, prepared-statement, md5

I have a login system that requires a username, password and ID. Passwords in database are encrypted in MD5 format. My test password is `test1`, which after encrypting is `5a105e8b9d40e1329780`. User on login screen should type `test1` as a password and be allowed into system. I just keep on getting my pop out message.

My SQL query looks like this:

```
String SQL = "SELECT login_judge.username, login_judge.password ,criminalrecords.ID FROM login_judge, criminalrecords "
           + "WHERE username = ? and password = md5(?) and ID = ?";
pst = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
pst.setString(1, usernameF.getText());
pst.setString(2, passwordF.getText());
pst.setString(3, caseNoF.getText());

rs = pst.executeQuery();
if(rs.next())
{
    // rest of code
}
else
{
   // joption pane displaying info that something is wrong.
}
```

From phpMyadmin

```
UPDATE  `w1283057`.`login_judge` SET  `password` = MD5(  'test1' ) WHERE  `login_judge`.`username` =  'test1';
```

Comment: What's your pop out message?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis its just JOptionPane."details are wrong/ do not match system records" more or less something like this

Comment: Then you have no such user in your database. When you insert the user, do you use md5 to hash the password?

Comment: @Maciej Are you sure you have a matching ID in the criminalrecords table?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Well such user do actually exists. The way i do it is simply type into table his username and password ( where password is set to function MD5) and it automatically hashes the password

Comment: @EtienneMiret yes everything was working before i started playing around with hashing the passwords

Comment: Show us your insert statement.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis updated my original question

Comment: The only thing I can see is what @EtienneMiret says, one of username, password, or ID do not match your row in the database.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis but when i remove from sql md5(?) and leave only ?. and change password in database to be text (not hashed) everything works. Its just the problem i see with program/or sql encrypting/decrypting the password. But again i dont know what is exactly happening

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Well so you can't really see anything wrong with it can you ?

Comment: @MaciejCygan Not with what you show here. Try (with mysql command line client) to insert a user with md5 and see what is in the row. Then try to retrieve it with java code.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis So answer has been found. Just didn't realize that my field was 20chars, but md5 is 32chars. Just had to extend the max value of chars allowed in database :). Anyway thank you for your time

Comment: Happy you got it, good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your password field is too short for the MD5 hash. It should have space for at least 32 chars, but it looks like you have defined it with maximum 20 chars.

Compare the output from md5(test1) with the value from your table:

```
5a105e8b9d40e1329780d62ea2265d8a
5a105e8b9d40e1329780
```

Since the hashes are not equal, the login is rejected.

If you can't change the column definition you can cut the hash with the `substring` function:

```
       + "WHERE username = ? and password = substr(md5(?), 1, 20) and ID = ?";
```

Comment: oh yes true! as md5s are 32chars and i forgot i have set max 20chars for password. So it is now all solved i just edited the column def :) thank you for pointing to me this little error i have made

Comment: Your answer is very simple and it is working I had the same problem